Any Solution for?? Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "HTTP_Header" not found in /talentbase.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/classes/Kohana/Response.php on line 123?
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct script access.');
/**
 * Response wrapper. Created as the result of any [Request] execution
 * or utility method (i.e. Redirect). Implements standard HTTP
 * response format.
 *
 * @package    Kohana
 * @category   Base
 * @author     Kohana Team
 * @copyright  (c) 2008-2012 Kohana Team
 * @license    http://kohanaphp.com/license
 * @since      3.1.0
 */
 
class Kohana_Response implements HTTP_Response {

    /**
     * Factory method to create a new [Response]. Pass properties
     * in using an associative array.
     *
     *      // Create a new response
     *      $response = Response::factory();
     *
     *      // Create a new response with headers
     *      $response = Response::factory(array('status' => 200));
     *
     * @param   array    $config Setup the response object
     * @return  Response
     */
    public static function factory(array $config = array())
    {
        return new Response($config);
    }

    // HTTP status codes and messages
    public static $messages = array(
        // Informational 1xx
        100 => 'Continue',
        101 => 'Switching Protocols',

        // Success 2xx
        200 => 'OK',
        201 => 'Created',
        202 => 'Accepted',
        203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',
        204 => 'No Content',
        205 => 'Reset Content',
        206 => 'Partial Content',

        // Redirection 3xx
        300 => 'Multiple Choices',
        301 => 'Moved Permanently',
        302 => 'Found', // 1.1
        303 => 'See Other',
        304 => 'Not Modified',
        305 => 'Use Proxy',
        // 306 is deprecated but reserved
        307 => 'Temporary Redirect',

        // Client Error 4xx
        400 => 'Bad Request',
        401 => 'Unauthorized',
        402 => 'Payment Required',
        403 => 'Forbidden',
        404 => 'Not Found',
        405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
        406 => 'Not Acceptable',
        407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
        408 => 'Request Timeout',
        409 => 'Conflict',
        410 => 'Gone',
        411 => 'Length Required',
        412 => 'Precondition Failed',
        413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
        414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
        415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
        416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
        417 => 'Expectation Failed',

        // Server Error 5xx
        500 => 'Internal Server Error',
        501 => 'Not Implemented',
        502 => 'Bad Gateway',
        503 => 'Service Unavailable',
        504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
        505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported',
        509 => 'Bandwidth Limit Exceeded'
    );

    /**
     * @var  integer     The response http status
     */
    protected $_status = 200;

    /**
     * @var  HTTP_Header  Headers returned in the response
     */
    protected $_header;

    /**
     * @var  string      The response body
     */
    protected $_body = '';

    /**
     * @var  array       Cookies to be returned in the response
     */
    protected $_cookies = array();

    /**
     * @var  string      The response protocol
     */
    protected $_protocol;

    /**
     * Sets up the response object
     *
     * @param   array $config Setup the response object
     * @return  void
     */
    public function __construct(array $config = array())
    {
        $this->_header = new HTTP_Header;
        **...**

Why is this error is being shown as in this image below ??

Please explain the reason. i got PHP 8.2 running on server. What could be the reason.
in my opinion it is unable to resolve the HTTP_Header to either \system\classes\Kohana\HTTP\Header.php class or ...\system\classes\HTTP\Header.php as both files are available at their location.
Do we have a solution for this issue ??
How can we resolve it ??

Is this Kohana, the “object oriented HMVC framework built using PHP5” that is officially documented as deprecated and hasn’t had a commit in almost a decade, Koseven, the fork that at least gets to PHP 7 (and might have branches for 8), or something else?

@ChrisHaas how do i upgrade to that version fork of Kohana. Thanks by the way

I'm not familiar with this project in any way, just what I showed. On the Koseven GitHub home there's a link to an upgrade guide. Just remember, Koseven says they are targeting PHP 7, they just have some experimental branches that PHP 8 work appears to be started on. If this is an existing install, I'm not sure about the longevity of this project and I think I might recommend starting to look at migrating.
